how to show the continuity?
$\forall W=(W_1,W_2)$, I define
\begin{align}
    f(V)=\begin{cases}
        \frac{\sqrt{R^2(v_1^2+v_2^2)-(W_1v_2-W_2v_1)^2}-(W_1v_1+W_2v_2)}{R^2-(W_1^2+W_2^2)}, & W_1^2+W_2^2\neq R^2\\
        \frac{v_1^2+v_2^2}{2(W_1v_1+W_2v_2)}& W_1^2+W_2^2 =R^2.
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
I want to show that the function f(V) is continuous at $ W_1^2+W_2^2 =R^2$, where $V=(v_1,v_2)$.
I appreciate any help.

You've written $f$ as a function of $V$ (presumably with fixed $W$), but according to your comment, you seem to be checking if $f$ is continuous as a function of $W$ (which suggests you're fixing $V$). Could you clarify whether $V$ is fixed, $W$ is fixed, or neither (i.e. $f$ is supposed to be continuous function of $(V, W)$)?

Yes, you are right. Question eddited!

I find it helpful to go back to vectors. You have a vector $v = (v_1, v_2)$, an orthogonal vector $u = (-v_2, v_1)$, and you are considering the function:
$$f(w) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} - w \cdot v}{R^2 - \|w\|^2}, & \text{if } \|w\| < R \\
\dfrac{\|v\|^2}{2w \cdot v} , & \text{if } \|w\| = R.\end{cases}$$
The projection of $w$ onto $u$ is $\operatorname{proj}_u w = \frac{(w \cdot u)u}{\|u\|^2}$, and the projection of $w$ onto $v$ is $\operatorname{proj}_v w = \frac{(w \cdot v)v}{\|v\|^2}$. Because these vectors are orthogonal to each other, their spans are orthogonal complements of each other, and so $\operatorname{proj}_u w + \operatorname{proj}_v w = w$ (this can be verified with components too). By Pythagoras,
$$\|w\|^2 =  \left\|\frac{(w \cdot u)u}{\|u\|^2}\right\|^2 + \left\|\frac{(w \cdot v)v}{\|v\|^2}\right\|^2 = \frac{(w \cdot u)^2}{\|u\|^2} + \frac{(w \cdot v)^2}{\|v\|^2}.$$
Since $\|u\| = \|v\|$,
$$\|w\|^2\|v\|^2 = (w \cdot u)^2 + (w \cdot v)^2.$$
This can also be verified with components. Now,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} - w \cdot v}{R^2 - \|w\|^2} \\
= \, & \frac{\left(\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} - w \cdot v\right)\left(\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v\right)}{(R^2 - \|w\|^2)\left(\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v\right)} \\
= \, & \frac{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2 - (w \cdot v)^2}{(R^2 - \|w\|^2)\left(\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v\right)} \\
= \, & \frac{R^2\|v\|^2 - \|w\|^2\|v\|^2}{(R^2 - \|w\|^2)\left(\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v\right)} \\
= \, & \frac{\|v\|^2}{\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v}.
\end{align*}
Now, can we show that $f$ is continuous at some $w$ such that $\|w\| = R$? It relies on showing that
$$\frac{\|v\|^2}{\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v} \to \frac{\|v\|^2}{2w^* \cdot v}$$
as $w \to w^*$, where $\|w^*\| = R$, and in order to avoid the limit expression being nonsensical, we also assume $w^* \cdot v \neq 0$. This is true when $\|v\| = 0$, but otherwise, this is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} + w \cdot v \to 2w^* \cdot v.$$
Given $w \cdot v \to w^* \cdot v$, it is further equivalent to
$$\sqrt{R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2} \to w^* \cdot v.$$
Here, we run into an issue: we automatically have to assume $w^* \cdot v > 0$. We know $w^* \cdot v \neq 0$, so the function makes sense, and if we have $w^* \cdot v < 0$, then the left hand side, being always positive, cannot limit to the right hand side. So, to proceed, we must refine our search for suitable $w^*$ to those where $w^* \cdot v > 0$. When this is the case, we get another equivalent limit:
$$R^2\|v\|^2 - (w \cdot u)^2 \to (w^* \cdot v)^2.$$
Finally, using our finding with Pythagoras's theorem once more, we get our final equivalent limit:
$$\|v\|^2(R^2 - \|w\|^2) - (w \cdot v)^2 \to (w^* \cdot v)^2.$$
Since $w \to w^*$, $\|w^*\| = R$ and both the dot product and norm are continuous, this limit is indeed true.
So, in conclusion, your function is continuous on its boundary at all $w$ where $w \cdot v > 0$. When $w \cdot v = 0$, it is undefined, and when $w \cdot v < 0$, it is discontinuous.
